# 6502 Emulation Enhanced Basic Infinite Loop $C000 to $E0ED

Tags: javascript, emulation, addressing-mode, 6502

I finally got to the point where my 6502 emulator passed all of the tests in AllSuiteA.asm, but my emulator is failing to emulate Enhanced Basic, which I have loaded at $C000.  What happens is PC slowly climbs up to $C03E, and then JSRs to $C892.  After that it steadily rises until $C908, where it JSRs again to $E0ED, and then JMPs indirectly to $0.

Why is Enhanced Basic infinitely looping, despite AllSuiteA saying my emulator was fine?

Here are the relevant functions:

**Opcodes:**

JSR:

```
case "JSR": 
    var t = pc + 1;
    memory[0x0100 + sp] = (t & 0xFF00) >> 8;
    sp--;
    memory[0x0100 + sp] = t & 0x00FF;
    sp--;
    pc = address - opcode[2];
break;
```

JMP:

```
case "JMP":
    pc = address - opcode[2];
break;
```

**Addressing Modes:**

IND:

```
case "IND":
    var b1 = memory[pc + 1];
    var b2 = memory[pc + 2];

    var mem = (b2 << 8) | b1;

    var bb1 = memory[mem];
    var bb2 = memory[mem + 1];

    address = (bb2 << 8) | bb1;
break;
```

ABS:

```
case "ABS":
    var b1 = memory[pc + 1];
    var b2 = memory[pc + 2];

    address = (b2 << 8) | b1;
break;
```

Note: opcode[2] is the number of bytes of the opcode being executed

[And here is a JSFiddle of the running program.](https://jsfiddle.net/ku49jzww/)  Included in this fiddle is a hexadecimal representation of ehbasic.bin.

Comment: Just to be clear: you're subtracting `opcode[2]` because later in your code you have something like `pc += opcode[2]` that it's cleaner just to allow to happen in that order? A real 6502 would have incremented the PC upon fetching each byte and would load it only in the last cycle, meaning that there's no such subtraction, which makes it look a bit jarring but I don't think it's a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: as you have your assemble configured, your CPU needs to simulate a reset, not just jump in at `C000`. Jump in at `FF80` if you just want to fix things in a single line.

---

Working from the source code:

`C892` is `LAB_CRLF`, which should "print CR/LF".

The first thing that routine does is load A with `0D` and then `JSR LAB_PRNA` to output that. That takes you up to `C8ED`.

The code there compares the character to be printed to ' ' and branches to `LAB_18F9` / `C90A` upon discovering that it's printing a control character.

At `C90A` is the long jump to `E0ED`, which is `V_OUTP`. That's just an indirect `JSR` through `VEC_OUT`, which is at `0207`. Your code appears to find only `00`s at `0207` and `0208` so vectors incorrectly.

It looks like you're using `min_mon.asm`. That sets up the relevant input/output vectors as part of the reset routine at `FF80` (which is reached from the 6502 reset vector, at `FFFC`). However your emulator doesn't emulate a reset, it just starts with `PC = C000`.

Hence the vectors are never initialised and the jump, though correctly emulated, doesn't go to where it should.